# Python: create dictionary element as modified value of existing element at initialization step

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Is there any way to achieve something like:

```
test = {
    'x' : 1,
    'y' : test.get(x) + 1 }
```

This will obviously fail, because 'test' doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you have a use-case for this or is it purely out of interest?

Comment: When you are defining the values of `x` and you know it why you want to use `get` method to do that job for you??????

Comment: It sounds like you want to tranform a list of keys into a dictionary, given an initial value for the first key and a function to transform the previous value to the next.

Comment: @RedX this one: 'x': 'verylongline', 'y': 'verylongline' + 'some suffix'.

Answer (score 0):

```
# solution #1
test = {"x" : 1}
test["y"] = test["x"] + 1

# solution #1.1
test = {"x" : 1}
test.update(y=test["x"] + 1)

# solution #2
x = 1
test = {"x": x, "y": x+1}

# solution #3
# (will obviously break as soon as you want to use a callable as value...)

def yadda(**kw):
    d = kw
    for k, v in kw.items():
        if callable(v):
            d[k] = v(d)
    return d

test = yadda(x=1, y=lambda d: d["x"] + 1)

# solution #4 - attempt at making #3 more robust

class lazy(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __call__(self, d):
        return self.f(d) 

def yadda(**kw):
    d = kw
    for k, v in kw.items():
        if isinstance(v, lazy):
            d[k] = v(d)
    return d

test = yadda(x=1, y=lazy(lambda d: d["x"] + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems that you want this:

```
x = 'verylongline'
suffix = 'some suffix'

test = {
    'x' : x,
    'y' : x + suffix }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test['y'] = test['x'] + 1
```

If you want to change the value of y whenever x gets updated then you have to use this code in a def and call the def whenever x gets updated